# Changes in design not reflected on activity

Tags: android, android-activity, background

I am trying to show data from my DataObject on my Activity. Everything works fine and do not crash anywhere but my views are not updated with the information.
I'm begginner on android, I know this...
Please Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this);
        vp = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail, null);

        String object_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("getIn"); // Get object_id from Intent

        DataQuery query = DataQuery.get("Id");
        query.getInBackground(object_id, new GetCallback<DataObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(DataObject object, DataException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                        TextView price = (TextView)vp.findViewById(R.id.priceD);
                        price.setText((String) object.get("price"));


                        TextView productD = (TextView)vp.findViewById(R.id.productD);
                        productD.setText((String) object.get("product"));

                        ImageView  thumbnail=  (ImageView)vp.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
                        thumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) object.get("image"));

                        TextView descriptionD = (TextView)vp.findViewById(R.id.description );
                        descriptionD.setText((String) object.get("description"));


                  //  }

                } else {
                    // Error

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you sure, `e` is not null and done method is called? Try using logcat to get the result.

Comment: I'm sure, because I debug the application, and I see the data of every variable, but I see, in the method set text, but the activity don't refresh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have setContent to Activity why are you inflating same XML again?
Remove these lines:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailActivity.this);
    vp = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail, null);
```

Also remove its reference when finding view. Just use:

```
TextView price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.priceD);
```

Currently, your changes in background method changes view inside inflated view and not on Activity's view so changes are not visible. Remove above code and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is my first app in android...

Comment: Hey Miki, I see you edited and removed your code from Question. But was the solution I provided was not correct?

Comment: yes, but the manager of stack overflow ,blocked me, for my question...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

to refresh an `Activity` from within itself.

Comment: It finist but when i startactivt it starts again and it entry in a loop

Comment: The easiest way is to call onCreate(null); and your activity will be like new.